# При создании директории изменился регистр

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Загрузил изображения со стороннего сервера, при этом создавалась директория, если ее нет, в нее сохранялась сама картинка, вставлялась соответствующая запись о местоположении в БД. Все работало нормально (какой бы ни был регистр в url openserver на windows находит изображение) и только при переносе сайта на ubuntu apache узнал, что регистр некоторых записей и папок отличается, как следствие не загружаются изображения. При чем только некотрых без закономерностей.  В чем может быть причина и как это исправить (заново загружать изображения не вариант - все были подфотошоплены ) ?

```
// сохранение картинок 
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $path   = public_path().'\images\\';
    //$file   = $request->file('file');
    $images = car_image::where('path', '');

    foreach ($images as $image) {

        $ch = curl_init($image->cc_url);
        $filename = str_random(2).'\\'.str_random(2).'\\'.str_random(4) .'.jpg';

        // создаем каталог если он не создан 
        $dirname = dirname($path.$filename);
        if (!is_dir($dirname))
        {
            mkdir($dirname, 0755, true);
        }
        // загружаем и сохраняем файл 
        $fp = fopen($path.$filename, 'wb');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);

        $image->path = $filename;
        $image->save();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

[image: каталог изображения и запись в БД]

Comment: Как вариант решения проблемы - переименовать все в нижний регистр(или верхний) и тоже самое проделать с базой данных

Comment: Скорее всего так и придется сделать + повозиться с одинаковыми именами, которые появятся. Я вот не понимаю, почему изменился регистр, причем не везде, а выборочно

Comment: Он скорее всего не изменился а стал таким как указано в БД в скриптах, просто в win системах регистронезависимые пути в отличии от nix